# azure rest api file creation .failed to authenticate the request. formed correctly including the signature. Response code : 403 this error

Tags: java, azure, rest, api

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Base64;


public class TestCloudStorage {
private static final String account = "account-name";
private static final String key = "key";


 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  createFile();
 }


 public static void createFile() throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
  String urlString = "https://" + account + ".file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/mydirectory/myfile";
  System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy");
  System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
  getFileRq(connection, account, key);
  connection.connect();
  System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
  System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());
  BufferedReader br = null;



  if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200 && connection.getResponseCode() != 201) {
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getErrorStream())));
  } 

  else {
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
  }
  System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
 }



 public static void getFileRq(HttpURLConnection request, String account, String key) throws Exception {
  SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
  String stringToSign = "PUT" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\nx-ms-content-length:1024" + "\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-type:file" + "\nx-ms-version:" + "2015-02-21" + +"/" + account + request.getURL().getPath();
  System.out.println("stringToSign : " + stringToSign);
  String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);
  System.out.println(auth);
  request.setRequestMethod("PUT");
  request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
  request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
  request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
  request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-content-length", "1024");
  request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
  request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-type", "file");
  request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
 }


 private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
  Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
  mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
  String authKey = new String(Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
  String auth = "SharedKey " + account + ":" + authKey;
  return auth;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment and format the code in question so that it is at least readable.

Comment: i tried to format the code was not able to format my code on stack overflow.

Comment: @RahiMuzammil   I have done it for you!  Next time, please try to post formatted code as unreadable code it very tough to read and solve for the community member. have look here how you can [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron BIG +1 for your patience and taking time to format the code!

Comment: @GauravMantri For the sake of community sometimes need to be patient. I help the new member. Thanks for your inspiration.

Comment: @RahiMuzammil No problem, learn how to format :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because you're specifying `Content-Type` with `application/octet-stream` value in your request header but not in your `stringToSign`. Please change your `stringToSign` to something like:

```
String stringToSign = "PUT" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "application/octet-stream\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\nx-ms-content-length:1024" + "\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-type:file" + "\nx-ms-version:" + "2015-02-21" + +"/" + account + request.getURL().getPath();
```

or you could remove `Content-Type` from your request headers as by default the content type would be `application/octet-stream`.

**UPDATE**

I also noticed a missing new line character after `2015-02-21` (value of x-ms-version). Can you add that?

```
String stringToSign = "PUT" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "application/octet-stream\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\nx-ms-content-length:1024" + "\nx-ms-date:" + date + "\nx-ms-type:file" + "\nx-ms-version:" + "2015-02-21" + "\n/" + account + request.getURL().getPath();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the last code you tried. Also, please print the output of `stringToSign`.

Comment: One more thing: When you get the error, read the error response stream as string. That will have more detailed error message. Please include that as well in your question.

Comment: but i have made the changes.

Comment: What are you talking about? You should be able to edit your question. Just click on "edit" link below the question, update the question with your latest code and then save edits.